# Positioning the divs using bootstrap in different viewports

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 and I would like to create three divs that change their position depending on the current viewport. I think this should be possible, but somehow i cannot conclude how this can be established using bootstrap. So I have 3 divs, lets call them img text and ex. 
I would like them to work for the different viewports as the following image suggests.

[image]

I have played around with pull and push, but that does not seems to solve my problem. I am looking for a “pull-up class” so that i can move for example a div to the right (using push) and then be able to move it up.

This is an example that still does not work..

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
    img
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-6 col-md-push-0">
    exp
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT 1: This code is one of the answers to this question that exactly targets the core of the problem. I updated the example image and added another one to illustrate the problem.
This code produces this behaviour (Notice the empty space on the right side of the sm view)

[image]

EDIT 2: The accepted answer provides a solution for a fixed size text, img, exp.

Comment: Add some CSS to  your question. However, why can't you use @media queries for `device-width` and just set the `exp` div to `float:right` on tablets and `float:left` on desktop (no `float` for phone)?

Comment: Try to replace `col-sm-push-6` with `col-sm-offset-6 col-md-offset-0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the behavior you want, you need to use the bootstrap push and pull classes.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
    img
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-6 col-md-push-0">
    exp
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see it in action here: http://www.bootply.com/CNGe5KxWxK

More info about pushing and pulling can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Comment: `col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-6 col-md-push-6` can be simplified to `col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6`

Comment: @cvrebert Yes, that is true. I left it like this to be more explicit as to what the intended behavior is.

Comment: I just tested your solution and i updated the question accordingly. I hope it is clearer now

Comment: @M.C. All you need to do for that behavior is to add a clearfix element right before your exp column. '<div class="hidden-xs clearfix"></div>'. I'll edit the answer to reflect this. http://www.bootply.com/Ca662J148G

Comment: I just tested the bootply.com/Ca662J148G and i see the same behaviour in the sm viewport. On the right side, you can see red, white then blue. I need to see red then blue

Comment: @M.C. I see. I was referencing the old image.

Comment: @M.C. So far, I have been unable to get that exact layout without duplicating content. Here is an example: bootply.com/FDrPLfdstd However, if you do know the height of the text and img elements (which I suspect you don't) you can use a media query and one css property to get the effect without duplicating content. bootply.com/CNGe5KxWxK

Comment: Thank you for that. I will try the one with the css and I will let you know. A very nice trick with "top-margin: -50".